# Encrypt in python then decrypt in dart

Tags: python, dart, cryptography, client-server, p2p

I generate pair keys in dart, send the pem encoded public key via socket to python, recieve & retrieve the key from pem, then i encrypt a plaint text with the retrieved public key and send the cipher text back to dart via socket. when i try to decrypt the ciphertext with the matching private key im getting the following error:  `[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): decoding error #0      OAEPEncoding._decodeBlock (package:pointycastle/asymmetric/oaep.dart:452:7)` . Im kind of sure that the problem is with the encoding in python's encrypt function but i couldn't catch it.

**1-** Generating RSA keys in dart (pointycastle) and then send the pem encoded public key to python.

```
String produceKey(RSAPublicKey my_pub) {
String public_pem = rsa_helper.CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(my_pub);  
return "//encryptedKEY" + public_pem; // communication via socket
```

}

**2-** Recieve key and encrypt with it in python (using Cryptography library)

```
  public_key =serialization.load_pem_public_key(bytes(mykey,'utf8'), backend=default_backend())
                    message = "send 10 BTC to halit"

                    message = base64.b64encode(bytes(message,'utf8'))

                    encrypted_message = public_key.encrypt(
                        message,
                        padding.OAEP(
                            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
                            algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
                            label=None
                        )
                    )
                    b = base64.b64encode(encrypted_message)
                    base64_str = b.decode('utf8')
//then send  cipher text to client
```

**3-** Decrypt the recivied cipher text

```
        String cipher_text = serverResponse.substring(9);//take the cipher text from the socket.(first 9 character identifier so we pass them)
        Uint8List plain_text = rsaDecrypt(my_private,cipher_text);//decrypts cipher text given private key and the cipher text
        print(plain_text);
```

Notes: socket communication is tested and looks to be well,
Pem public key that is sent is matching with the one is generated.

```
Uint8List rsaDecrypt(RSAPrivateKey myPrivate, Uint8List cipherText) {
final decryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())
..init(false, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(myPrivate)); // false=decrypt

return _processInBlocks(decryptor, cipherText);
}
  //decrypt method from pointycastle package.
```

**Test Case**

having pair keys:

```
  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCPGT5j+2qdxrKp
   trWW4hZcIwdacuduH16J7FO/0URzKoXdA5M5xVXwU/6HxREkKp+A+XUQN8HZCILP
   mQzXkmWCLWNQP92o6WUeZQW6bcXYt11mS9JmDhDPXwuiq33vEMJFlXi1L1Wrq2nR
   WVHKsJAuwswCfEjBfVdrJjut88JGXD/w5Et3t3A/zVX2eGAM1sn97kt57/PESObP
   RVLB+avTVAEAu4Qb3/uMvRlmDVgE6eE6pm5La+ObyVrfDdP41ly7zNf3VqgtM0dM
   OuurDmIGigXLvbrbIsx/TVxmwXvtreWhSyBISKMUMPB2NgcnvEXjXkt+PO00dGcN
   8NI3erI9AgMBAAECggEAeHXWqJHfqVu30NgmuxItong2W3S4z2IG0nIn+iRuy8fz
   Eh9NU2eENaBvdtl02Y4r4YWdfv6A53ObsqhzQBFT9CbDIK3yqZt37QM7tDluQEXz
   kQao4hJbIkYvZEua4qGn+K2gBF4Jb08H8ByRlt/VMBf5Zuo60O7zpRZ1TLUTSOhi
   7V0Teuu8djneHRtLzPgnfvGa1Ok6f4ObZGFgoZqTXK9HXxEc4+nICQoYc8BsMUlL
   iPFnBzU4MlvF5xUT4bYWqQjsQBoHM7zVrpAtZ3xKeSSdbkEWivYkt36h+RQLm3SM
   /1M5Ji92MjoFnLawh2XbZ+QD3W4owSvtd91n48lH/QKBgQDEbBI/7kfew6WO921D
   jaEEIRwDxOn0kYZhoGozU8zUWUQBfCfDR5MNJWELvioCfTWcyAJ/+ysalSezYIHU
   nuSGe8YrFTWI/xkGdUk1rfdSehbcnoPBwAM7wgW+twIdJpCAk6VbVMdh2hQNKDEN
   0hAawk2PGr+2zm0qHuJhL0benwKBgQC6gKrbyv9XV6Th7blU0cnvY1fF3pdBKBFx
   U8oABAXi+8db2nUUxZ/zbOUUKFYd0yX5SukXArek8xrzPjf52CReL845k6M76fDy
   uSK4xQz900rueRaOANU4XxW+n+afti6CuoB5IINKRIne1S9ZEpmbtVWi0Y59+ANf
   1GmXgictowKBgFcD7V3HCK3GDIz2TcBUeNVkeY2t6VsAMQEE2KdeY2pbFUZ3IwJe
   reVv/rr+BoxNvbdz36+krGa9VvYfNcTkkyaEpLinT60eHY7/3GvcYql2DrSzwHjP
   wF7zyCnB1zzkvbVIM0PvndhajPF7MagGvD2ugD96QR4R+shjIDSfhgzPAoGBAI5b
   8o+NNzULYH9YP1RgQnzpXrFaBCinFhFkPNegOoIVYApcCWzOoRZls8KcO4fOibjt
   lliLKXTOYG71ujKK6s++O/M1H693FgWgjcFuIEmLxDGd2jqQpjC+W9HDKn4UyRHe
   nHxY9f51rKucHOUnznrNgs2imdrLun+mmuccYR1zAoGAHDkVep3Hy7cXVGwJzVeS
   lvAHadFlQ4TcvJqVv+uNB8hRsH7BZqsyWfnepWuy7MychkuWGHpiIpzBFxeMFvi1
   aKa1yjNARIHQLpXvZntVVM7pb2hWFKTNyOwKMJrp8o2h0DJKOar7jlLyNs3ZIDFM
   n7w9iHpANOewTaT8svyFnxI=
   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjxk+Y/tqncayqba1luIW
XCMHWnLnbh9eiexTv9FEcyqF3QOTOcVV8FP+h8URJCqfgPl1EDfB2QiCz5kM15Jl
gi1jUD/dqOllHmUFum3F2LddZkvSZg4Qz18Loqt97xDCRZV4tS9Vq6tp0VlRyrCQ
LsLMAnxIwX1XayY7rfPCRlw/8ORLd7dwP81V9nhgDNbJ/e5Lee/zxEjmz0VSwfmr
01QBALuEG9/7jL0ZZg1YBOnhOqZuS2vjm8la3w3T+NZcu8zX91aoLTNHTDrrqw5i
BooFy7262yLMf01cZsF77a3loUsgSEijFDDwdjYHJ7xF415LfjztNHRnDfDSN3qy
PQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

plain_text = "Send To Halit 10BTC";
```

the cipher text im getting in python is:

```
jQO/VTb2lJut94GB5ABgV5gXsd2ee3x++EUz9FaMMEn8zxSisfUY7qiaAtwfV8bIOw+rcvfmyfIdxngSDS1B6qj5gp/OWDRhcExY7rfPTbY0Y1unuS4N8+C4dO1sFDANKSwl5tDfrs1ZN99J8H24jO9TjB0EPAAezxO8/DyjPRhe0wiBunObz0iiyVK73APoHJ1atCQ8cjKXUipCELpvog5k+XAdVwBeLb6N+Yw9LNUCMlIMXalj2koZ6IwbMY687qx2XlSgIH11pZC8ArRg82CCW/zi5gYckbeWVkC75ne/O3q3wd7h8/t8rdD/62hIyucV68udIFW7amCSN8/XFQ==
```

**Getting Error mentioned above** (Decoding error).

**EDIT**

Here is my server code in python which takes public key pem and encrypt some plain text and send the cipher text back to client

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_public_key
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import base64
import socket
import threading
import time
import traceback

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5005
clients = []
client_names = []

def messageHandler(client,message:str): # send the message to the client 
    if (not client == "osmanClient"):
        client.send(message.encode("utf-8"));
        time.sleep(0.3)

def handle(client,address):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            if (msg):
                print(msg)
                if len(msg) > 6 and msg[:6] == "//name":
                        client_names.append(msg[6:])
                        clients.append(client)
                        messageHandler(client,"//sendKEY") # request public key from client 
                                             
                elif(len(msg)>14 and msg[:14]== "//encryptedKEY"):   # if the client send the pub key                                    
                        mykey = msg[14:] # the pem string of public key
                        public_key =serialization.load_pem_public_key(bytes(mykey,'utf8'), backend=default_backend()) # retrieve public key from the pem
                        message = "send 10 BTC to halit"
                        message = base64.b64encode(bytes(message,'utf8')) 
                        encrypted_message = public_key.encrypt(
                            message,
                            padding.OAEP(
                                mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
                                algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
                                label=None
                            )
                        )                   
                        b = base64.b64encode(encrypted_message)
                        base64_str = b.decode('utf8')     
                        print(base64_str)
                        messageHandler(client,"//hmacKey"+base64_str)# send the message to the client
                else:
                    print("KEY EKLEMEDE HATA OLUŞTU")

            else:
                print("ELSE KOLUNA DUSTU   :::   " + msg)

        except:
            # print(msg[6:]+"  :  NA BURAYA GİRDİ")
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            client.close()
            clients.remove(client)
            break
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((IP, PORT))
    server.listen()

    # Sunucu, bağlantı isteği gelene kadar dinlemeye devam ediyor
    print("Sunucu dinlemeye başladı...")
    while True:
        # Bağlantı isteği geldiğinde, kullanıcıyı kabul edip ve handle fonksiyonunu çalıştırarak mesajları dinlemeye başlayoruz
        client, address = server.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,address)).start()
```

**and on Client side**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:encrypt/rsa.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'crypto.dart' as rsa_helper;

void main() async {

  Random random = new Random();
  int randomPort = random.nextInt(15000)+50000;
  final pair = rsa_helper.CryptoUtils.generateRSAKeyPair();
  final my_private = pair.privateKey as RSAPrivateKey;
  final my_public = pair.publicKey as RSAPublicKey;
  String mysocketIP = "localhost";
  print("Your IP:   $mysocketIP");
  print("Your PORT:  $randomPort");
  var sleepDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 400);
  var clientList = [];
  String serverIP = "localhost";
  int serverPort = 5005;
  Socket serverSocket = await Socket.connect(serverIP, serverPort);

  serverSocket.listen(
        (Uint8List data) async {
      String serverResponse = String.fromCharCodes(data);
       if(serverResponse.substring(0,9) == "//hmacKey"){
        print('cipher text recieved from server!'); // we recieved the cipher text
        String cipher_text = serverResponse.substring(9);
        String plain_text = decrypt_message(cipher_text, my_private);
      }

      else if(serverResponse =="//sendKEY") {
        sleep(sleepDuration);
        stdout.write(".");
        sleep(sleepDuration);
        print(".");
        // send the encoded pem public key to server
         serverSocket.add(utf8.encode("//encryptedKEY"+ rsa_helper.CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(my_public)));
      }
      else{
        print("server:   $serverResponse");
      }

    },
    onError: (error) {
      print("Client: $error \n");
      serverSocket.destroy();
    },
    onDone: () async {
      print('Client: Server left. \n');

    },
  );
  serverSocket.add(utf8.encode("//nameTopaco"));
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 50));
  serverSocket.close();
}
```

where as crypto.util class is class with the following utility code:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils/master/lib/src/CryptoUtils.dart

**Solution**
Thanks to [Topaco](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco), In client when decrypting we should decrypt like

```
String server_response = serverResponse.substring(9);
          print(server_response);
          final Uint8List cipherText = base64Decode(server_response);
          final decrypted = rsaDecrypt(my_private, cipherText);
          final decoded = utf8.decode(decrypted);
          final b64Decoded = base64Decode(decoded);
          print(decoded);
          print(utf8.decode(b64Decoded));
```

Comment: What is `decrypt_message()`? If it is a user-defined method, post the implementation, otherwise post a link to or at least the name of the library used (this actually applies to all libraries used). What does `serverResponse.substring(9)` contain? Post complete test data (public and private key, plaintext and ciphertext). The error message could point to a padding issue.

Comment: Thanks For your response, i've tried to explain each step with a test case provided.

Comment: Your code is still not executable: On the one hand `_processInBlocks()` is missing, on the other hand the call of `rsaDecrypt()` with the concrete test data (loading the key, passing/decoding the ciphertext), see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Since on my machine the decryption of your test data works with PointyCastle, the bug is probably somewhere in this unposted code. Maybe a bug in `_processInBlocks()` or a missing/wrong decoding etc. But this is pure speculation, since these code parts are missing.

Comment: i apologize for my bad-style question, _processInBlocks, rsaDecrypt are all methods from pointycastle library. Here is the link.
https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/tutorials/rsa.md

Comment: i know that rsa is not deterministic in nature but in dart i get cipher texts such as "L\^B%ÿ\^Y6ÊSõnX'\^D\^S8p~ZuòpNÍ\^^:±¢.ªÇ"  and in python i get like i mentioned above. so im thinking that the problem is within encoding the cipher text's bytes itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250782/discussion-between-basel-kilzieh-and-topaco).

Comment: *... _processInBlocks, rsaDecrypt are all methods from pointycastle library...* Nope. `_processInBlocks()` is a method from the examples and is not part of the actual library. If you use something like that, you have to post the code or at least a link. Or do you expect us to search all the examples/tutorial?